# Opengl ES texture is not applied to object

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to opengl es on android and learning opengl by doing some examples. I am using two program to draw 3 objects. The following code loads the texture and draws a square. But it is appearing as a black square instead of applying the texture to the body.

my fragment-shader code

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
}
```

my vertex-shader code

```
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

attribute vec4 a_Position;

uniform mat4 u_Matrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
    v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;
}
```

my object vertex buffer

```
float [] vBufferFloat = new float[] {
            -0.2f, -0.2f, 1f,
            0.2f, -0.2f, 1f,
            0.2f, 0.2f, 1f,
            -0.2f, 0.2f, 1f,
            -0.2f, -0.2f, 1f,
        };
```

my texture buffer

```
float [] texCoordinate = new float[] {
            -0.2f, -0.2f, 
            0.2f, -0.2f, 
            0.2f, 0.2f, 
            -0.2f, 0.2f,
            -0.2f, -0.2f,
        };
```

my onSurfaceCreated && onDrawFrame code

```
public void onSurfaceCreated() {
        cloudRendereProgram = ShaderHelper.createProgram(mContext, R.raw.sky_texture_vertex_shader, R.raw.sky_texture_fragment_shader);
        cloudTextureId = Utils.loadTexture(mContext, com.elpis.gamecontroller.R.drawable.cloud);
        aTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");
        uMatrixLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "u_Matrix");
        aPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "a_Position");
        uTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "u_Texture");
    }

public void onDrawFrame() {
        float [] mVMatrix = new float[16];
        GLES20.glUseProgram(cloudRendereProgram);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vBuff.buffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mVMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, mVMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.cloudTextureId);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(uTextureLocation, 0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texBuff.buffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureLocation);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 5);
    }
```

and my texture loader helper code

```
public static int loadTexture(Context ctx, int resId) {
        final int [] textureHandle = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
            return 0;
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        final Bitmap imgTexture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), resId);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, imgTexture, 0);
        imgTexture.recycle();

        return textureHandle[0];
    }
```

When I run the android application all I see is a black square instead of seeing a texture of cloud. So, I would appreciate if anyone point me in the right direction.

Two quick questions; Is it valid to create multiple opengl program objects with different shaders and run them concurrently?

[UPDATE]

The problem was on the onDrawFrame(). I had to use vBuff.buffer.position(0) and texBuff.buffer.position(0) to be able to draw the texture correctly.

```
public void onDrawFrame() {
            float [] mVMatrix = new float[16];
            GLES20.glUseProgram(cloudRendereProgram);
            // FIX 
            vBuff.buffer.position(0);
            texBuff.buffer.position(0);
            // END FIX
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vBuff.buffer);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mVMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, mVMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.cloudTextureId);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(uTextureLocation, 0);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texBuff.buffer);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureLocation);
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 5);
        }
```

Comment: are you calling setEGLContextClientVersion(2); somewhere?

Comment: yes it is called in the MainActivity onCreate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling glEnableVertexAttribArray for your texture coords. Add this line to your onDrawFrame():

```
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureLocation);
```

Call glGenerateMipmap after you upload the texture texImage2D() in your loadTexture() function, to make sure all mip-map levels are valid:

```
glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Also, move these calls from your surfaceCreated() function to the start of drawFrame():

```
aTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "a_TexCoordinate");
uMatrixLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "u_Matrix");
aPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "a_Position");
uTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cloudRendereProgram, "u_Texture");
```

(it could be that these variables are not bound properly or the GL context is not yet properly set up in surfaceCreated())

A debugging tip for OpenGLES. Add this function to your code (it's from the Android OpenGLES samples):

```
public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
```

you can call it after each OpenGLES call, and pass in a String that can be whatever debugging message you want. If anything goes wrong then you'll get an exception instead of just silent failure which will leave you scratching your head trying to figure out what went wrong. Make sure to remove it from your final build to avoid force closes.

Comment: P.S. regarding your second question, it's obviously possible to have two OpenGLES apps open at the same time and switch between them, however when one loses focus its GL context is no longer valid, and it has to recreate its textures etc when it gets focus back. So I don't think you could have an app doing rendering in the background. I'm not 100% sure on this however so I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but enabling the attrib does not solve the problem :( .

Comment: I think my question is ambiguous because by program I meant opengl es program object; not the android Activity. I think you are mentioning about having multiple opengl es activities. I will edit my question to remove the ambiguity. Thanks for the reply though :) .

Comment: Try adding GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0); to your loadTexture function right before you call glBindTexture(). It probably won't make a difference because that's the default but give it a try anyway.

Comment: also, call glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D); after you call texImage2D()

Comment: the result is still the same even after adding glGenerateMipmap()

Comment: thanks for the reply, and a very useful tips. I have found the problem.